# Get size and size on disk of files

Tags: windows, powershell

I have a simple PowerShell script that makes a list of all files in a directory and prints that to a .txt file, as follows

```
$currentDir = 'C:\files'
Get-ChildItem $currentDir -Recurse -Force | ForEach-Object {
    $_.BaseName + "|" + $_.Extension + "|" + '{0:N2}' -f ($_.length/1MB) >> files_log.txt
}
```

However that only gets the size of the file. I want to get the size on disk of said file. The output should be something like:

```
BaseName | Extension | Size | Size_on_Disk
file | .pdf | 0.06 | 1.00
file2 | .mp3 | 0.30 | 1.00
```

I've searched but I only get results on how to get the sum of the sizes on disk for files within a folder. I haven't found a proper way to access said property from `ForEach-Object`.

**How can I get the `Size On Disk` parameter as seen in the properties of the file from PowerShell?**

Comment: Maybe you could use [this](https://www.opentechguides.com/how-to/article/powershell/133/size-on-disk-ps.html) cmdlet.

Comment: Thanks @Vivere. I was looking for an specific property within the ForEach-Object, but it seems that there isn't and you have to build your own. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do some math tricks. According to this comment from [here](https://www.opentechguides.com/how-to/article/powershell/133/size-on-disk-ps.html) by `DelphicOracle` you could calculate it based on your drive's allocation unit size.

```
function Get-SizeOnDisk {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    [OutputType([int64])]
    param (
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, Position = 0, ValueFromPipeline = $true)]
        [string]
        $Path
    )

    process {
        $absolutePath = ($Path | Resolve-Path).Path
        $item = Get-Item $absolutePath
        $volume = Get-Volume $item.PSDrive.Name

        $d = [int][System.Math]::Ceiling($item.Length / $volume.AllocationUnitSize)
        return $d * $volume.AllocationUnitSize
    }
}

'myItem.ext' | Get-SizeOnDisk
```

Basically, you check how many times the Drive's AllocationUnitSize fits in the actual length of the file, and if the division has a rest, you ceil it.

Comment: Awesome solution, although shouldn't `Floor` be used? because excess data that doesn't fit into one unit will consume a new unit so you want to add this data not throw it away?

Comment: If you have a file of 4100 bytes, and your Drive's Allocation Unit Size is 4096, you need 8192 bytes to store that file because you can't cut information from it.

Comment: That's exactly what I'm saying, `Ceiling` returns 4096 but it should return 8192, so you need `Floor` to get bigger number.

Comment: Nope, Ceil(4100/4096) = 2; 2 * 4096 = 8192. Floor(4100/4096) = 1; 1 * 4096 = 4096. Possibly we are not talking about the same thing. What I do in the cmdlet, I check how many times 4096 fits in the length of the file, `ceiled` to accommodate for the need of one more block of 4096.

Comment: You're correct, I got the MSDN docs wrong, sorry.

Comment: This won't always provide the correct answer. When dedupe is enabled, size on disk will be 0 but size will be the file's total amount of data. I think with NTFS compression (although not very effective...) size on disk will give you the compressed size of the file